# Supporting Ruby 1.9's hash syntax in Ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax, backwards-compatibility, ruby-1.8

I'm writing a Ruby gem using the `{key: 'value'}` syntax for hashes throughout my code. My tests all pass in 1.9.x, but I (understandably) get `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'` in 1.8.7.

Is there a best practice for supporting the 1.8.x? Do I need to rewrite the code using our old friend `=>`, or is there a better strategy?

Comment: Ruby 1.8 is going to fade out soon. You don't need support for it.

Comment: Is that a popular opinion? I am certainly looking for input on what other Gem authors are doing. I know there is a big push within the Ruby community to get everyone on the 1.9 train. I personally don't mind leaving 1.8 behind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you're out of luck, if you want to support 1.8 then you have to use `=>`. As usual, I will mention that you must use `=>` in certain cases in 1.9:

1. If the key is not a symbol. Remember that any object (symbols, strings, classes, floats, ...) can be a key in a Ruby Hash.
2. If you need a symbol that you'd quote: `:'this.that'`.
3. If you use MongoDB for pretty much anything you'll be using things like `:$set => hash` but `$set: hash` is a syntax error.

Back to our regularly scheduled programming.

Why do I say that you're out of luck? The Hash literal syntaxes (both of them) are hard-wired in the parser and I don't think you're going to have much luck patching the parser from your gem. [Ruby 1.8.7's `parse.y`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_8_7/parse.y#L2503) has this to say:

```
assoc    : arg_value tASSOC arg_value
             {
                 $$ = list_append(NEW_LIST($1), $3);
             }
         ;
```

and `tASSOC` is `=>` so hash literals are hard-wired to use `=>`. [1.9.3's](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/parse.y#L4798) says this:

```
assoc    : arg_value tASSOC arg_value
             {
             /*%%%*/
                 $$ = list_append(NEW_LIST($1), $3);
             /*%
                 $$ = dispatch2(assoc_new, $1, $3);
             %*/
             }
         | tLABEL arg_value
             {
             /*%%%*/
                 $$ = list_append(NEW_LIST(NEW_LIT(ID2SYM($1))), $2);
             /*%
                 $$ = dispatch2(assoc_new, $1, $2);
             %*/
             }
         ;
```

We have the fat-arrow syntax again (`arg_value tASSOC arg_value`) and the JavaScript style (`tLABEL arg_value`); AFAIK, `tLABEL` is also the source of the restrictions on what sorts of symbols (no `:$set`, no `:'this.that'`, ...) can be used with the JavaScript-style syntax. The current trunk `parse.y` matches 1.9.3 for Hash literals.

So the Hash literal syntax is hard-wired into the parser and you're stuck with fat arrows if you want to support 1.8.

Comment: very nice and thorough answer, mu. It looks like I might have to rewrite the instances where I use JS style syntax. Just wish there was a way to support legacy versions without writing legacy code. This might be the best bet though.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 1.8.7 does not support the new hash syntax.

If you desperately need hash syntax on the non-YARV c-based implementation of Ruby, there is a totally unsupported 1.8 head branch, so you [can](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/installing/) do

```
rvm install ruby-head --branch ruby_1_8 ; rvm ruby-head
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.8dev (2011-05-25) [i386-darwin10.7.0]
```

but upgrading to 1.9 is the way to go.

Comment: I think the intention of JackCA is to provide a gem that a Ruby 1.8 user can use, not that JackCA is using Ruby 1.8. So I don't think this will help.